# What makes a field not groupable

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql, math, aggregate

I'm trying to use an aggregate query, but one of the fields I want to group by is not groupable (saw it in the soql error and then verified groupable=false in the metadata).

It's just a number field that holds an integer (number 2,0 in salesforce field spec-speak).

Is there a trick to make it groupable?  Any way around this problem? I don't want to write hundreds of lines of code just to average a list by this field.

Comment: Can you provide more specific detail about the configuration of the custom field which you are trying to group by?

[Support for Field Types in Aggregate Functions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions_field_types.htm)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what makes it "groupable".  The [Considerations When Using GROUP BY](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_group_by_considerations.htm) does mention it:

> Some object fields have a field type that does not support grouping.
> You can't include fields with these field types in a GROUP BY clause.
> The [Field](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm#i1427375) object associated with [DescribeSObjectResult](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm#topic-title) has a [groupable](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm#field_groupable)
> field that defines whether you can include the field in a GROUP BY
> clause.

Although not exactly elegant, you could try to copy the not groupable field to a groupable field via a workflow rule and then group by that one instead.

Comment: Did the extra field copy with a workflow.  Salesforce seems arbitrary sometimes.

Answer (score 7):

It appears that you can not group by custom number fields and not the ability to group by formulas is a [request](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000HlNt) on the ideaexchange so you will need to create a workflow rule that copies the number to a text field.

Note that most standard number fields cannot be grouped by as well but a few like account.numberofemployees can be.

Answer (score 2):

For those people who come across this old but still relevant question, see the more complete community wiki answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/235529/27021)