# Error as MALFORMED Query in Developer console (Group by Rollup, Group by Cube)

Tags: dynamic-soql, developer-console

Why do I get this ERROR as :MALFORMED Query in Developer console?

I'm trying to use :Group By Roll or Group By CUbe to get the subtotals and grand totals.

When I tried this Query:

```
SELECT  id,gmod__Quantity__c,  gmod__Amount__c,GROUPING(gmod__Quantity__c) grpQty, GROUPING(gmod__Amount__c) grpAmt ,COUNT(id) oppfc from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c GROUP BY CUBE(gmod__Quantity__c, gmod__Amount__c) ORDER BY GROUPING(gmod__Quantity__c), GROUPING(gmod__Amount__c)
```

Error as :

> MALFORMED QUERY [object Object]: gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c GROUP
>   BY CUBE(gmod__Quantity__c, gmod__Amount__c) ^ ERROR at
>   Row:1:Column:183 field 'gmod__Quantity__c' can not be grouped in a
>   query call

Similarly I just tried using  Grouping By One Rollup Field

```
SELECT  gmod__price__c,COUNT(Name) cnt
    FROM gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c
    GROUP BY ROLLUP( gmod__price__c)
```

Grouping By Two Rollup Field

```
SELECT  gmod__price__c,gmod__Amount__c ,COUNT(Name) cnt
FROM gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c
GROUP BY ROLLUP( gmod__price__c,gmod__Amount__c)
```

It does not give any o/p result.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can not use all fields to group by. A field has to be groupable. There seems to be some mystery about when a field is groupable and when it isn't, also see this question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5818/what-makes-a-field-not-groupable

Comment: @Lex:Quantity field is a number data type,price is a currency data type and Amount is formula field currency  data type.so it not possible for the currency or number data type to be grouped