# vertical bar chart in visualforce?

Tags: visualforce

I got error like this :

> [System.UnexpectedException: field 'IKAM_Year__c' can not be grouped in a query call]

how can I resolve this error? can anybody help me.

class:

```
public Month[] getMonths() {
    Month[] months = new Month[] {};
    for (AggregateResult ar : [select count(Id) ,IKAM_Year__c,Countries_delivered_volume__c from IKAM_Data__c
                                              group by IKAM_Year__c, Countries_delivered_volume__c LIMIT 10                        
    ]) {                                        
        months.add(new Month((Decimal )ar.get('IKAM_Year__c'),(Decimal)ar.get('Countries_delivered_volume__c')));
    }
    return months;
}
```

Comment: Some info in [What makes a field not groupable](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5818/what-makes-a-field-not-groupable).

Answer (score 1):

From the SOQL documentation on [Considerations When Using GROUP BY](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_group_by_considerations.htm),

> Some object fields have a field type that does not support grouping. You can't include fields with these field types in a GROUP BY clause. The Field object associated with DescribeSObjectResult has a groupable field that defines whether you can include the field in a GROUP BY clause

Specifically, you could see whether or not your field is able to be used with GROUP BY by running the following code:

```
system.debug(IKAM_Data__c.IKAM_Year__c.getDescribe().groupable);
```