# Change format fields in SOQL

Tags: soql, soql-injection

I do the next SOQL and works:

```
SELECT FieldString FROM Account GROUP BY FieldString HAVING COUNT(FieldString)>1
```

But when I do the next SOQL doesn't work:

```
SELECT FieldDouble FROM Account GROUP BY FieldDouble HAVING COUNT(FieldDouble)>1
```

Is it possible to make a format change for the SOQL to work? Or is there an alternative to making this SOQL work?

Comment: Do you get any error messages when running the second query? If so you should [edit] those into your question.

Comment: What's the **purpose** behind this query? What are you hoping to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

[What makes a field not groupable](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5818/what-makes-a-field-not-groupable)

This was somehow answered here.

However, to your case, custom number fields cannot be grouped by, same as text formulas with value `TEXT(FieldDouble)`.

**The only solution if you do not want to modify your SOQL is to create a text field that will be updated from a workflow anytime the FieldDouble changes with its value.**

Answer (score -2):

This query is not going to work because you are not doing any aggregation.

HAVING clause only works on aggregations. Available aggregations in SOQL are: AVG(), COUNT(), COUNT_DISTINCT(), MIN(), MAX(), SUM().

If you want to perform your SOQL query, you should aggregate your FieldDouble field and group by groupable fields.

Working example:

```
SELECT LeadSource, COUNT(Name)
FROM Lead
GROUP BY LeadSource
HAVING COUNT(Name) > 100
```

Documentation:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_having.htm

Comment: No, you cannot group by this field (custom number field). It can be checked: ```system.debug(Account.FieldDouble.getDescribe().isGroupable());``` which gives **false**.